# Workflow to trigger upon creating a new record

Tags: workflow

Using workflows and not a trigger, how does one create a rule criteria that causes the workflow to execute upon creating a new custom record ?

E.g. When I'm adding a Customer__c record i'd like the workflow to trigger an email update.

I did some googling. Is [ISNEW](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm#ISNEW)() or ISCHANGED() the way to go for this formula?

I tried putting ISNEW() in the rule criteria and it gives me an error, "Function ISNEW () may not be used in this type of formula".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the Evaluation criteria as 'Evaluate the rule when a record is created'. and simply put 'true' in workflow rule criteria formula.